# Startup File default handlers for SysTick

Tags: c, startup, cortex-m, stm32cubeide

I'm using the STM32F030 and CubeIDE and am trying to rationalize my own code and build some libraries to share across projects.

In the current project I don't need to do anything upon SysTick but currently need an empty `SysTick_Handler` in my code to override the current default in the startup file (as that causes the system to get stuck in a loop forever).

My question is two fold...

1. Is there a way of disabling the Interrupt on tick is I don't need it - I still need the tick to run as is polling it. Even if I did I would presumably need the empty `SysTick_Handler` function as I could not guarantee to get the interrupt disabled before a tick happens.
2. I was thinking about writing my own empty weak function for my libraries so the default is to nothing and carry on if a tick happens. I could then override this in my applications if necessary. Is it bad practice to delete the

```
.weak      SysTick_Handler
.thumb_set SysTick_Handler,Default_Handler
```

in the startup file and replace with a C function?

Should add something in the startup file that does what I want instead, e.g. an alternative Default_Handler. Any ideas what that would look like?

Comment: Can you clarify why having your own empty `SysTick_Handler` to override the weak in startup file is a problem?

Comment: Its simply because I wanted to create a library with an empty weak function that I can override if I need some applications to do something on a tick interrupt.